# 14.04 LTS Black screen after installing bumblebee (MBP 9,1)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm kindof a noob when it comes to Ubuntu/not windows so please pardon my inexperience.

I've been messing around with Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro (9,1 mid 2012, non retina), installed as a dual boot with OS X (with rEFInd).

In my noobishness I tried to have a wack at Bumblebee to see if GPU switching would work. Well, now I get a black screen after the purple Ubuntu screen with the dots. It appears the computer is booting up, and if I type my password and hit enter, it appears to login, just there's no video output after the Ubuntu screen, just black.

For reference I was using the most recent nVidia proprietary drivers (331.xx i think) supplied by the "additional drivers" utility. (card is a GT 650M)

Is there any way to uninstall bumblebee/fix this, or should i just give up and reinstall (its not a actively used install, but i have put a good number of hours into configuring it)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/bumblebee.conf` needs to be edited...
if you do not use nvidia-current (-> nvidia-331)

there should be no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` of any kind

```
sudo update-alternatives --config i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

and

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

(or the mac equivalent) should be set to mesa.

Answer (score 0):

To remove rather than fix ..

Login using a [rescue CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery), mount your disks, enable networking and drop to root. Then remove Bumblebee bee using one of the methods (I'd purge) below and reinstall Nvidia 331.

**Uninstall just bumblebee-nvidia**

```
sudo apt-get remove bumblebee-nvidia
```

This will remove just the bumblebee-nvidia package itself.

**Uninstall bumblebee-nvidia and it's dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove bumblebee-nvidia
```

This will remove the bumblebee-nvidia package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

**Purging your config/data too**

If you also want to delete your local/config files for bumblebee-nvidia then this will work.

Caution! Purged config/data can not be restored by reinstalling the package.
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee-nvidia
Or similarly, like this

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove bumblebee-nvidia
```

**Reinstall Nvidia drivers**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-331 nvidia-331-update
```

source : http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/b/bumblebee-nvidia/en/uninstall/index.html